# Capture Screen in libGdx

Tags: libgdx

I want to capture screen in libGdx . I use this code for my problem. On Desktop it work . But when I run on my android , I can't find image capture screen. How can I fix it? Thanks for reading my question.

```
public class ScreenshotFactory {

private static int counter = 1;

public static void saveScreenshot() {
    try {
        FileHandle fh;
        do {

            if (Gdx.app.getType() == ApplicationType.Desktop)
                Infor.linkScreenShot = "D://chupngoc" + counter + ".png";
            else
                Infor.linkScreenShot = Gdx.files.getExternalStoragePath()
                        + counter + ".png";
            Infor.nameImage = counter + ".png";
            fh = new FileHandle(Infor.linkScreenShot);
            counter++;
        } while (fh.exists());

        Pixmap pixmap = getScreenshot(0, 0, Gdx.graphics.getWidth(),
                Gdx.graphics.getHeight(), true);
        PixmapIO.writePNG(fh, pixmap);
        pixmap.dispose();
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
}

private static Pixmap getScreenshot(int x, int y, int w, int h,
        boolean yDown) {

    Gdx.gl.glPixelStorei(GL20.GL_PACK_ALIGNMENT, 1);

    final Pixmap pixmap1 = new Pixmap(w, h, Format.RGBA8888);
    ByteBuffer pixels1 = pixmap1.getPixels();
    Gdx.gl.glReadPixels(x, y, w, h, GL20.GL_RGBA, GL20.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,
            pixels1);

    Pixmap pixmap = pixmap1;

    if (yDown) {
        // Flip the pixmap upside down
        ByteBuffer pixels = pixmap.getPixels();
        int numBytes = w * h * 4;
        byte[] lines = new byte[numBytes];
        int numBytesPerLine = w * 4;
        for (int i = 0; i < h; i++) {
            pixels.position((h - i - 1) * numBytesPerLine);
            pixels.get(lines, i * numBytesPerLine, numBytesPerLine);
        }
        pixels.clear();
        pixels.put(lines);
    }

    return pixmap;
}
```

}

Comment: Sorry . I fixed . I add permission on Android Mainfest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem lies here...

```
fh = new FileHandle(Infor.linkScreenShot);
```

This way of creating a FileHandle is for the desktop only and will not work on Android.

You should create a file using `Gdx.files.external` instead...

```
fh = Gdx.files.external(Infor.linkScreenShot);
```